# Wikitude - prob with camera orientation in landscape mode

Tags: ios, wikitude

I'm using wikitude for my augmented reality mobile app project. I got this problem when my camera in landscape mode.

First attempt:

[image]

Second attempt:

[image]

Third attempt (problem here):

[image]

Comment: @wikitude , can u check it out

Answer (score 0):

In case this tip might someone. So, in your viewController add following code snippets.

```
[self.architectView setShouldRotate:YES toInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```